# rewrite rule for files with pattern to go to subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, design-patterns, mod-rewrite

I have files with this pattern :

```
(a[0-9]+\.htm)$
```

Considering file names a1180717200.htm or a1245862800.htm : normally they would be in root for the domain I am working with. Instead they have been moved to a new directory /archives so the files are now in :

> ```
> thedomainiamworkingwith.com/archives/a1245862800.htm
> ```

I have tried a few things but I have no success. The root is occupied by a working wordpress site, with its normal .htaccess file set up. So I need to know what the redirect or RewriteRule would be, as well as how to put it in the .htaccess file without messing up the current wp install.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to redirect your pages of this pattern to archives directory?

You can try something like this

RewriteRule ^(a[0-9]+.htm)$ thedomainiamworkingwith.com/archives/$1 [R=301,L]